# What's happening when you synthesize a subclass' variable?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

I have a superclass and a subclass. I can access the variable `some_property` (declared in the superclass) via `self.some_property` in the subclass.

However if I try to access the instance variable directly with `_some_property`, I'll get the error `'Use of undeclared identifier _some_property...'`.

Using `@synthesize some_property = _some_property` silences this warning.

Whats going on when I re-synthesize the property?

Comment: Are you explicitly synthesizing in the superclass as well? You can't redeclare an ivar in the subclass like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating **another** ivar named `_some_property` — and also overriding the getter method to return the value of this new ivar. The compiler gives you an error about this *if* the base class's `@implementation` (i.e. the implicit declaration of its `_some_property` ivar) is visible at the site of the `@synthesize` in the subclass.

*(By the way, don't do this!)*

You can demonstrate to yourself by inspecting the Obj-C runtime:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface Base : NSObject
@property id foo;
@end


@interface Derived : Base
@end

@implementation Derived

@synthesize foo=_foo; // the compiler doesn't know about Base's _foo yet, so this is OK...

- (instancetype)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _foo = @"I'm derived";
    }
    return self;
}
@end

@implementation Base  // after Derived to avoid the error
- (instancetype)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _foo = @"I'm base";
    }
    return self;
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        Derived *obj = [Derived new];
        NSLog(@"getter returns %@", obj.foo);

        unsigned int count = 0;

        // Examine Base ivars
        NSLog(@"Base ivars:");
        Ivar *ivars = class_copyIvarList([Base class], &count);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            NSLog(@" %s = %@", ivar_getName(ivars[i]), object_getIvar(obj, ivars[i]));
        }

        // Examine Derived ivars
        NSLog(@"Derived ivars:");
        ivars = class_copyIvarList([Derived class], &count);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            NSLog(@" %s = %@", ivar_getName(ivars[i]), object_getIvar(obj, ivars[i]));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
getter returns I'm derived
Base ivars:
 _foo = I'm base
Derived ivars:
 _foo = I'm derived
```